# Obtener los values de una calculadora y usar los operadores logicos

Tags: java, android

Hola perdonen a lo mejor es muy fácil mi pregunta pero no lo puedo resolver, tengo una calculadora que intenta hacer las operaciones básicas pero, no me obtiene el segundo valor para realizar la operación, no entiendo muy bien porque. A continuación el código.

```
public TextView calText;
    public double value1, value2, ans;
    int operation;


     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_constraint);
        calText=findViewById(R.id.cal_text);

     }

    public void bt0(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"0";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }

     public void bt1(View v) {
         String cap=calText.getText().toString();
         cap=cap+"1";
         calText.setText(cap);
     }
    public void bt2(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"2";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt3(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"3";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt4(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"4";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt5(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"5";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt6(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"6";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt7(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"7";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt8(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"8";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt9(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+"9";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void bt_decimal(View v) {
        String cap=calText.getText().toString();
        cap=cap+",";
        calText.setText(cap);
    }
    public void sum (View v) {
        try {
            String aux1=calText.getText().toString();
            value1=Double.parseDouble(aux1);
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            calText.setText("");
            operation=1;
        }
    }
    public void rest (View v) {
        try {
            String aux1=calText.getText().toString();
            value1=Double.parseDouble(aux1);
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            calText.setText("");
            operation=2;
        }
    }
    public void mutliplication (View v) {
        try {
            String aux1=calText.getText().toString();
            value1=Double.parseDouble(aux1);
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            calText.setText("");
            operation=3;
        }
    }
    public void division (View v) {
        try {
            String aux1=calText.getText().toString();
            value1=Double.parseDouble(aux1);
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            calText.setText("");
            operation=4;
        }
    }
    public void percent (View v) {
        try {
            String aux1=calText.getText().toString();
            value1=Double.parseDouble(aux1);
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            calText.setText("");
            operation=5;
        }
    }
    public void equals (View v) {
        try {
            String aux2 = calText.getText().toString();
            value2 = Double.parseDouble(aux2);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
        calText.setText("");

        if (operation==1) {
            ans=value1+value2;

            }else if (operation==2) {
                ans=value1-value2;

            }else if (operation==3){
                ans=value1*value2;

            }else if (operation==4){
                if(value2==0){
                    calText.setText(R.string.error);
                }else {
                ans=value1/value2;

                }
            }else if (operation==5) {
                ans=value2*(value1*100.0);
            }
            calText.setText("" + ans);
            value1=ans;
     }

     public void clear (View v) {
         calText.setText("");
         value1=0;
         value2=0;
         ans=0;
    }

    public void erase (View v) {
         if (!calText.getText().toString().equals("")){
             calText.setText(calText.getText().subSequence(0, calText.getText().length()-1));
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola a que segundo valor te refieres Jhon?

Comment: Hola, me refiero al valor que toma la calculadora para hacer la operación, es decir, al momento de usar el boton "+" no se borra la pantalla de mi calculadora y no puedo hacer la suma porque no toma el segundo valor para hacer las operaciones.